# Extract features and labels from a Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TextLineDataset that reads lines from a text file.

This dataset reads the file and returns it in a sliding window manner, so for example if my text file contains:

```
I am going to school
School is far from home
```

My dataset returns:

```
I am going
am going to
going to school
...
```

(Assuming I want 3 words at a time, sliding from one word at each step)

I am happy with that.

But now I want, for each sentence returned by the dataset, to extract the first 2 words and say they are my features, and to extract the last word and say it is my label

Of course I want it to be part of the computation graph (like my dataset) and not at running time

Here is my code:

```
sentences = tf.data.TextLineDataset("data/train.src")
words = sentences.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string]).values)
flat_words = words.flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)

flat_words = flat_words.window(3, 1, 1, True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3)).batch(4)

iterator = flat_words.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
sess.run(iterator.initializer)

print(sess.run(next_element))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just slot in one more mapping function. Something like this will map all but the last word as a set of features and just the last word as the label:

```py
def map_to_feats_and_lbl(x):
  return x[:-1], x[-1]
```

which we can slot in something like this:

```py
flat_words = flat_words \
  .window(3, 1, 1, True) \
  .flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3)) \
  .map(map_to_feats_and_lbl) \
  .batch(4)
```

and use in a similar way to what you were doing already:

```py
iterator = flat_words.make_initializable_iterator()
feats, label = iterator.get_next()


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
sess.run(iterator.initializer)

feat_val, label_val = sess.run([feats, label])
print (feat_val)
print (label_val)
```